# how to get a month and year from a column in database in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I have a table **actionhistory** have a column name **actiondate** which store the date, i want to get the month from actiondate as mon column and  year of actiondate as year

For example "select extract('month' from actiondate) as mon,extract('year' from actiondate) as year

how can i get the month and year in laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consideration :**

1. You have already created actionhistory model.
2. Store date is 30-03-2017 (day-month-year)

**Note**
    first() will return only one record. You can use ->get() for multiple record however you need to loop the result.

**Method 1:**

```
$result = actionhistory::select(DB::raw('MONTH(actiondate),YEAR(actiondate)'))->get();
```

**Method 2:**

```
$result = DB::table('actionhistory')->select(DB::raw('MONTH(actiondate),YEAR(actiondate)'))->get();
```

**Method 3:**

```
$actionhistory = new actionhistory();
$result = $actionhistory->select(DB::raw('MONTH(actiondate),YEAR(actiondate)'))->get();
```

In all above methods (1,2,3) result will contain following

```
[MONTH(actiondate)] => 3
[YEAR(actiondate)] => 2017
```

**Method 4 : with Carbon instance**

```
$result = actionhistory::first();
```

OR

```
$result = DB::table('actionhistory')->first();
```

OR

```
$result = $actionhistory->first();
```

Now include carbon and use format

```
$month = Carbon::parse($sql->created_date)->format('m'); // month will be 3
$year = Carbon::parse($sql->created_date)->format('y');  // year will be 2017
```